# Android webview position: fixed

Tags: java, android, webview, position, fixed

Anybody know a way to handle a page that's displaying blank due to a `position: fixed` in the page's CSS?

My android app is a browser and customers are complaining that [accounting research manager login](https://new.accountingresearchmanager.com) doesn't load. After looking into it that site is loading but nothing appears due to the CSS `position: fixed`. If I turn that off in chrome tools, the page appears.

Is there anything I can add to my app so the page will load like in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Since your web page uses javascript to load its content, you need to enable javascript in your Android webview and also configure it to handle the redirects the page does.

To do this, follow the steps below before loading the webpage url

1) Use the  [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) method to get a reference to your webview. Ex.:

`WebView webView = findViewById("The view id declared at the layout xml");`

2) Enable javascript:

`webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

3) Enable redirects and load the redirected page in the same webview:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It does. It's the last page, the login page that has the CSS with position fixed that's causing the problem

Comment: Have you tried the code above? My webview renders the login page successfully

Comment: Yes it has all that.

Comment: I'm having a hard time here to reproduce the bug, do you know if it's happening on a specific Android version?

Comment: It could be a specific version. It's currently set for 23. I can't check if that's the issue until I'm back at work tomorrow. It's also why I didn't post any code, I'm not comfortable posting work code.

Comment: Just so you know I have tested here on Android 24, 23 and 19 and the login page was displayed on all of them. I will wait for more info so I can investigate further.

Comment: I updated the compilesdkversion to 24. Still blank. And I updated the minsdkversion to 19 and it's still blank

Comment: When I mentioned the Android version, I actually meant the version of the OS running on the device you are using to test you app, not the sdk version used to compile the app. So let me ask one more question, do you know if your implementation worked on some devices? Or didn't work at all?

Comment: I ran it in 23 and 24 on a simulator.